# AS3(ActionScript) display 2480 x 3508 screen size from flash player?

Tags: actionscript-3, view, actionscript, scale, stage

I'd like to make a stage size with A4(300dpi).

2480 x 3508 px

If then I cannot see the proper size in flash player.
So I'm planning to make a reduction of stage like "248 x 350" / 90% contraction view.

How can I implement this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If I understand the question correctly*

You can create a `248` by `350` swf stage and use [`scaleX`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scaleX) and [`scaleY`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scaleY) properties of your A4 content (which can have actual size of `2480` by `3508`) to zoom in/out.

[Here](http://wonderfl.net/c/KwkY) is a small demo